# Enhanced for loop compiling fine for JDK 8 but not 7

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-7, language-lawyer

Consider the following code snippet, I stumpled upon after some refactoring, when checkin why the build server reported a broken build but it was fine in my IDE:

```
List<String> text;
...
for (String text : text) {...}
```

So, the same name is used for the String and the List within the for-each.

This is of course not very wise to do, but after following my nosiness before renaming it, I saw that the above code compiles fine with JDK 8, but gives the below error with JDK 7:

```
  error: for-each not applicable to expression type
        for (String text : text) {
                           ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    String
1 error
```

I know that changes were made to several parts in this area within the JDK - but can someone enlighten me on why exactly this behaviour occurs?

---

**Update:**
Since I got some comments about different behaviour, here's a full sample class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Strange {

    List<String> text = Arrays.asList("Max", "Alex", "Maria");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Strange().doSomething("Alex");
    }

    public void doSomething(String name) {
        for (String text : text) {
            System.out.println(text.equals("Alex"));
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the compile process and output (Windows 7 64bit):

```
C:\copy>c:\Projects\java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac.exe Strange.java
Strange.java:13: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
        for (String text : text) {
                           ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    String
1 error

C:\copy>c:\Projects\java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe Strange.java

C:\copy>
```

---

**Conclusion:**
I was so puzzled why my IDE (which uses 8) didn't complain about twice the same name in one statement - but now it is clear that it is not one statement. I really wonder why this point has so long been in place if the JLS states otherwise. But anyway, thanks for the insights I have received and the great answers (which made it hard for me to pick the best one).

Comment: He's not asking for a solution, but for an explanation. 
That's an interesting behaviour though, I'd like to know as well

Comment: I suspect text and text hide the same field. Java 8 may have been more relaxed about it and realize those are two different variables in the loop, but Java 7 does not. Did you try renaming the variable so they are different name?

Comment: @TheLaw: It's the other way round, it fails for 7. And of course, when using different names, it works for both.

Comment: @Mel: Thanks for pointing that out - of course I wouldn't normally do something like naming both the same - it just happened on accident and I only realised it after the broken build and started wondering about.

Comment: I tried compiling with JDK 8 (1.8.0_31) and I get the error "variable text is already defined in method"

Comment: @AlexanderRühl Its giving error in both versions I have checked it.

Comment: See my update concerning full example

Comment: I would still have my IDE fake a compile error because this just seems like a source of bugs waiting to happen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the reasoning, using the specified translation from the enhanced `for` loop to the traditional `for` loop, used by [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439463/2711488) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439404/2711488) is correct, there is an explicit specification about the scopes:

> #### [§6.3. Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)
>
> …
>
> The scope of a local variable declared in the *FormalParameter* part of
>   an enhanced `for` statement ([§14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2))
>   is the contained *Statement*.

([direct link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3-540))

Thus, the scope of the variable does not include the *Expression* of the enhanced `for` loop…

You can verify that this hasn’t changed, compared to [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3-540)
and [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/names.html#130473),
though both (I tried Java 6 `javac`) exhibit the contradicting behavior.

So this change in the compiler behavior is the fix of an old bug…

Answer (score 14):

This should actually compile fine for JDK 7 and 8.

Quoting JLS [section 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) (which is the same for the Java 7 specification):

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>       {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
>           (TargetType) #i.next();
>       Statement
> }
> ```

Rewriting the enhanched for loop with `Iterator`

```
for (String text : text) {...}
```

becomes

```
for (Iterator<String> it = text.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String text = it.next();
}
```

Then, quoting [example 6.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#d5e8689) of the JLS:

> A similar restriction on shadowing of members by local variables was judged impractical, because the addition of a member in a superclass could cause subclasses to have to rename local variables. Related considerations make restrictions on shadowing of local variables by members of nested classes, or on shadowing of local variables by local variables declared within nested classes unattractive as well.

As such, there is no compile-time error here because no restriction is made when shadowing a member variable by a local variable, which is the case here: the local variable `String text` is shadowing the member variable `List<String> text`.

Answer (score 6):

I would say it is a compiler bug in the particular version of the Java 7 compiler that you are using.

The earlier `text` is a field, and it is legal for the `text` local declared in the `for` statement to shadow a field.

Then we look at what the for loop means.  According to the JLS,

```
    for (String text : text) {...}
```

is equivalent to

```
    for (Iterator<String> #i = text.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
        String text = (String) #i.next();
        ...
    }
```

As you can see the inner `text` is not in-scope for the `text.iterator()` expression.

---

I tried searching the Oracle Java Bugs Database, but couldn't find anything that matched this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think the other answers are correct, let me be devil's advocate and offer the opposite view.

Obviously JDK 7 parses the foreach loop in such a way that the variable 'text' is also in scope after the ':'. To test this, I wrote the following method. It compiles and runs just fine in Java 1.7:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String text : new String[] {text = "hello", text, text, text})
        System.out.println(text);
}
```

Although others have said this is a bug in jdk 1.7 (and it probably is), I couldn't find anywhere in the JLS that specifically says the variable just declared is not in scope after the ':'. If it's not a bug, then Java 8 breaks compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Your build server may be compiling using a different jdk than your local machine. (Not just a different version number, but a completely different implementation.) Eclipse is one that uses its own compiler, I believe to facilitate its code hot-swapping.

<strike>Using the same name for the collection and the element ought to raise problems anywhere</strike>, but I have heard of and occasionally noticed Eclipse tolerating things that the Sun/Oracle JDK won't.

Comment: No, this only led me to the root of the problem. I have the latest 2 JDKs of 7 and 8 on my machine and compile the same code with each and get a compile error in 7 and none in 8.It has nothing to do with either IDE or OS.

Comment: If you're confident you were using the same JDK vendor for both tests, then I'd be inclined to report it as a bug (in 1.8), though I suppose it's possible that it's somehow related to the new lambda expressions support.

Comment: @BradMace It's actually a bug in 7. This should work.

Comment: I'm reluctantly convinced that it's necessary for Java to allow this based on some of the other answers. It's an awful way to write code though, and should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

This compiled fine for me. I'm using the Java 8 JDK, on Netbeans, on a 64 bit machine (Windows 7).

I believe this is a localization issue related to your IDE or compiler. I used your exact example, the output being

```
false
true
false
```

There was a warning given, stating that it is possible, but not recommended to hide a field with a local variable.

Comment: And what about java 7? It's there where the compile error occurs, 8 is fine for me too. Was a typo in title, but correct in question explanation.

Comment: I just tested on Java 7, and there was no difference in output:   compile-single:
run-single:
false
true
false