# Change in for loops in java 8

Tags: java

Consider this code :

```
public class Test
{
        static final Collection<String> info = new ArrayList<>();

        public static void main(String... args) {
                for (String info : info) {
                        System.out.println(info);
                }
        }
}
```

It compiles fine in java 8, but results in a compile-time error with java 7 :

```
Test.java:8: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
                for (String info : info) {
                                   ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    String
```

Of course I should not write such code. The real class in much bigger, and a rename of the field lead to something like this...

My question is : why is this happening ?
What evolution of the language made this legal in java 8 ?
I checked various java 8 changes lists, but couldn't find anything explaining this behaviour.

Can anyone point me to the change in java 8 that is responsible for this ?

Comment: Rename the collection to something else: `collectionInfo`, and retry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438842/enhanced-for-loop-compiling-fine-for-jdk-8-but-not-7

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is interpreting `info` as `String` and that's why it isn't `Iterable`

In the scope of the `for` loop, it already exist a variable with the same name of your array